# Pass specific properties of an object to the child component with Input decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

Assuming I have an object Customer as following :

```
export class Customer {

   id: number;
   name: string;
   premium: boolean;

   address: string;
   country: string;
}
```

In my parent component :

```
/*** stuff declaration */

@ViewChild(ChildComponent)
private childComponent: ChildComponent;

customer: Customer;
```

Child component :

```
/*** Stuff */

@Input()
public customerSubpart : any;

/*
customerSubpart properties expected:
id, name, premium
*/

save() : void {
   /* call service to save modifications */
}
```

I want that a click event on the parent template saves modifications done on the customerSubpart object within the save() method.
I can manage that with @ViewChild decorator but I need to **pass only a subpart** of the `customer` object to the `customerSubpart` object.
Do I really need to create a new model and inject it in the Customer model (or use inheritance) or there are cleaner ways to do that (best practices) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid creating another model, you could pass it in as an anon type. For instance, by passing

```
   { id: customer.id, name: customer.name, premium: customer.premium }
```

This, however, is not a good practice because you lose the typing advantage of Typescript.

Another solution that could serve your purpose, depending on how many properties you have to send, is to create an `@Input()` per property. So for instance, instead of `@Input() public customerSubpart : any;`
you could do

```
  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() premium: boolean;
```

A third option is to make the non- subpart properties optional properties, and then only send the properties you need. So your class would change to

```
export class Customer {

   id: number;
   name: string;
   premium: boolean;

   address?: string;
   country?: string;
}
```

This still runs the risk of your child component changing the latter properties accidentally, unless you forcibly stop it.

My recommendation would be to either use the second option or create a sub-Model, unless you do not need to fear the changes, in which case the third option would work too.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is the problem I have +100 model properties in the real app and I must choose the most reliable way. So, in order to be in the Typescript conventions the second option or the sub-Model solution should be picked. The Input decorator should provide more features by Angular team in the future. Be able to get the whole object or only parts of it. Thanks anyway !